# How to prevent .php page from refreshing after an .ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I've got a page called mathProblems.php that generates a series of math problems for a user and on submit of form with id='math_answers', makes an ajax call to grade the math questions and return the results.

The results are graded in mathProcess.php. On submit, I see the ajax call fire off, see the results of mathProcess.php returned and flash on screen before mathProblems.php refreshes and generates a new set of questions. I'm specifically perplexed at why a reload of mathProblems.php is happening and would appreciate any pointers.

Here is the .ajax call:

```
//displays user's current problem set results on the math page via getResponse
$('#submit_math').click(function(){
    var mathData = $('#math_answers').serializeArray();
    mathData.push({name: 'times', value: saved_times});
    var text = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "mathProcess.php",
        data: $.param(mathData),
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
    }).responseText;
    $('#problem_widget').html(text);
});
```

Comment: You need to prevent the default action using [`e.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/): `$('#submit_math').click(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); /* current code */ });`.

Comment: @joe Thanks. That worked. Although I don't understand why identical .ajax calls I'm making for other problem type modules work without that. What is the case that determines whether you need to block default or not?

Comment: Clicking a link or submitting a form takes you away from the page (assuming the link is not to an ID). So that is what you need to prevent.

Comment: Thanks @Jeron. And that's true even if the form doesn't have a specified action in the <form> tags and you're just acting on it via an .ajax call?

Comment: Forms without an `action` attribute submit to the same page, although officially you need to use `action=''` for that. So the same page gets reloaded instead of another one.

Comment: @Joe Your comment should really be an answer ;) and it's a good one!

Comment: @Joe's got the right idea, but I would put it on the form's submit even-handler instead. Something like: `$(#theForm').on('submit', function(e) { e.preventdefault(); // do stuff; });`

Answer (score -1):

As said in the comments you need to call preventDefault() on the event or make the event-handler return false:

```html
<form ... onsubmit="doSomething();return false;>
```

The easier way is not using forms at all or, if you want to use the form to access the input, place the button outside the form:

```html
<form name="bla">
    <input name="foo">
</form>
<input type="button" id="submit" value="submit" />
```

```js
$("#submit").click(function() {});
```

Comment: Why in the world would anyone ever put a `submit` button *outside* a form?

Comment: Sorry, that was not clear. You can either use a `type="submit"` outside the form OR a `type="button"` inside of it. But when working with Ajax (and i mostly do when it comes to user input processing) i totally avoid the `<form>`-Tag.